# Do linear regression for each entry of arrays of numbers in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have numpy arrays:

```
X = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [2,4,6,8,1],
     [1,0,2,5,6]]
```

Is there a way to do least-squares regression efficiently for all columns of the matrix? For instance, we consider the first column `[1,2,1]` as the target value while the feature value is the matrix x whose first column is set to zero

```
  X = [[0,2,3,4,5],
       [0,4,6,8,1],
       [0,0,2,5,6]].
```

Can I pass this matrix to numpy.linalg.lstsq and calculate all 5 least-squares regressions for each column?

Comment: What did you mean by: do a least-squares regression for the first column [1,2,1] with respect to other columns ? Use first column as target values and the other columns as input features?

Comment: @LéoBeaucourt yes

Answer (score 0):

Considering First column as the target values and others as features, you could do this (mat is the supposed name of your numpy array):

```
np.linalg.lstsq(mat[:,1:], mat[:,0])
```

where, mat[:,1:] select all rows for all columns except first and mat[:,0] select all row for first column. Take a look at the numpy doc for more details about linalg.lstsq: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Edit: If you want to apply lstsq for each combination of columns as the target and others as features, you cannot send directly the array to the function, you should use a loop as follow:

```
regr_results = []
for i in range(mat.shape[1]):
    regr_results.append(np.linalg.lstsq(np.delete(mat, i, 1), mat[:,i], rcond=1)[0])
```

You loop over the number of columns, select features column by deleting current target colum with the np.delete() and select target column with the mat[:,i] code. Then recovering result of lstsq (here I get only resulting coefficients with the [0] and append these results into a list.

Comment: But this is only for the first column as target values, right? How about if we consider each column to be target values and others as features?

Comment: You would do 5 differents regressions for each column as the target ? Then you need to should do use numpy.linalg.lstsq method 5 Times with different columns selection. Maybe using a for loop.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: You can't do 5 regressions by calling one time the linalg.lstsq. Why you fill the first column with 0? What is your main goal with this code?

Comment: The goal of the code is to find out the regression coefficients for each column as target values. The filling of zero would be similar to deleting the target column so that the final output, the coefficients, would have the same dimension as to how many columns the matrix is. Also, the filling of zeros would help me know which column was used as the target values because it would reflect zero as coefficient for that column.  I hope you get what I want to do here.